# CentOS 7 setting default port

Tags: centos, ssh

I've been doing some maintenance on a CentOS 7 server and I noticed that it wasn't using the default ssh port (22).

I changed it back to it's Port 22 in the sshd_config which works but when I try to use ssh it is still defaulting to the non standard ssh port.

How do I set the ssh port default back to 22 so I don't have to keep specifying -p 22 when I try to ssh

Comment: make sure you restart the service after any changes to the config file.

Comment: Check for a `Port` option in either the system wide `/etc/ssh_config` (note the lack of a `d`) or in the user's option at `~/.ssh/config` **on your client**. This is the configuration for your client and dictates which port the client attempts to connect to in the absence of the `-p` option.  The option you changed is on the server and dictates which port the service is listening to.

Comment: the ssh_config was the answer, could you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

On server part, check:

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep ssh /etc/services | grep 22
ssh             22/tcp                          # The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
ssh             22/udp                          # The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol
ssh             22/sctp                 # SSH

[root@localhost ~]# grep 22 /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
#Port 22
```